# Package: songs strange opening quotation marks

Tags: punctuation, songs

I'm typesetting a songbook, and I have to cite a title of the original
melody just under the current title.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwart}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{kurier}

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\noversenumbers
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Pieśń o~tym przypomni}[by={Andrzej Depo, 1960 r.},
                                  sr={Na melodię pieśni harcerskiej %
                                      ,,Płonie ognisko i~szumią knieje''}]
\beginverse
Wiatr Wołynia niesie pozdrowienia,
z~wszystkich lasów, pól i~łąk,
pieśń nadziei nad Bugiem rozbrzmiewa,
myśli łączy w~jeden krąg.
\endverse
```

However the polish quotation marks ,, are replaced with two comas.
[image: strange comas]

I don't need any notes or melody hints in this songbook so maybe
it is better to use verse environment and format the rest by hand?

Comment: +1 for a question about quotation marks that uses the correct tag [tag:punctuation] instead of [tag:quoting].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the optional argument of `\beginsong` you need an extra pair of braces around the opening quotation marks, as in `{,,}` , or to use `„` or `\quotedblbase`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwart}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{kurier}

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\noversenumbers
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Pieśń o~tym przypomni}[by={Andrzej Depo, 1960 r.},
                                  sr={Na melodię pieśni harcerskiej %
                                     {,,}Płonie ognisko i~szumią knieje''}]
\beginverse
Wiatr Wołynia niesie pozdrowienia,
z~wszystkich lasów, pól i~łąk,
pieśń nadziei nad Bugiem rozbrzmiewa,
myśli łączy w~jeden krąg.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161884/package-songs-strange-opening-quotation-marks/161885?noredirect=1#comment370772_161885), the problem is in how songs absorbs the value after `sr=`; *three* pairs of braces are necessary in order the comma is not mistaken, so

`sr={{{Na melodię pieśni harcerskiej ,,Płonie ognisko i~szumią knieje''}}}`

will also work.

Comment: So the **songs** package seems to disable macro in package **polski** which converts double coma to the proper quotation mark.

Comment: @user15941 Apparently, the problem occurs just in the optional argument for `\beginsong`. I've edited my answer mentioning this and providing several alternatives.

Comment: The problem is in how `songs` absorbs the value after `sr=`; *three* pairs of braces are necessary in order the comma is not mistaken: `sr={{{Na melodię pieśni harcerskiej ,,Płonie ognisko i~szumią knieje''}}}` works.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I've incorporated your comment into my answer.